# Possible to create \pgfplotstablenew without header?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'd like to create a (pgfplots)table from scratch, however, one without a header. So I'm trying to modify one of the examples in the `pgfplotstable` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
% define how the ’0’ column shall be filled:
create on use/0/.style={create col/set list={0,1,...,10}}%
}
% create a new table with 11 rows and column ’0’:
\pgfplotstablenew[header=false,columns={0}]{11}\loadedtable
% show it:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[header=false,empty cells with={---}]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

... however, it seems that this `0` is interepreted as a string, not number, especially since trying to use `columns={[index]0}` fails with:

> \! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '[index]0' from table '\loadedtable@@table@name '.

Otherwise, with the code as above, the following is typeset in the output:

[image: test03.png]

... and as the zero is printed twice, it is confirmed that the first one is actually a header.

So, my question is - is there a way to dynamically create a table in `pgfplotstable` without a header row?

Comment: for avoiding typesetting, use `every head row/.style={output empty row}`

Comment: Many thanks for that, @percusse - I'm otherwise asking this just so I can prepare an example for yet another question (I read .csv data without headers, and would like to simulate that in MWE through generated tables); but that tip is great to keep in mind. Cheers!

Comment: Also to note, in my pgfplots 1.5.1, I get: "I do not know the key '/pgfplots/table/create col/output empty row' and I am going to ignore it."; so I looked it up in documentation, and it isn't there either. Unfortunately, cannot update to latest version for the time being...